# using C++ tuple types as key in a map

Tags: c++, loops, tuples, sfinae

I am trying to map collection of values of different types into continuous space. To do that (efficiently) I need to know total size of all elements and offset of each of them. Getting total size if collection is given as a Tuple is easy. It also allows to pre-calculate offsets. I struggle with obtaining offset by type. To simplify example I am assuming that types within Tuple are going to be unique (in reality Tuple are going to have pairs of unique tag + non-unique value). Here is my current not-compiling attempt:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct A
{
    std::size_t size()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

struct B
{
    std::size_t size()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

struct C
{
    std::size_t size()
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

template <typename Tuple>
struct Foo
{
    const Tuple& tuple_;
    std::array<int, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value> array_;

    Foo(const Tuple& tuple) : tuple_(tuple)
    {
        std::cout << init() << '\n';
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    template <std::size_t INDEX = 0>
    typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value == INDEX, std::size_t>::type
    init()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    template <std::size_t INDEX = 0>
    typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value != INDEX, std::size_t>::type
    init()
    {
        auto offset = init<INDEX + 1>();

        std::cout << "index: "<< INDEX << "; offset: " << offset << '\n';

        array_[INDEX] = offset;

        return offset + std::get<INDEX>(tuple_).size();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    template <std::size_t INDEX = 0, typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value == INDEX, std::size_t>::type
    offset(const T&)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    template <std::size_t INDEX = 0, typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<(std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value != INDEX) && !std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type, T>::value, std::size_t>::type
    offset(const T& t)
    {
        return offset<INDEX + 1>(t);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    template <std::size_t INDEX = 0, typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<(std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value != INDEX) && std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type, T>::value, std::size_t>::type
    offset(const T&)
    {
        return array_[INDEX];
    }    
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    auto t = std::tie(a, b, c);
    using T = decltype(t);
    Foo<T> foo(t);

    std::cout << foo.offset(a) << '\n';
    //std::cout << foo.offset(b) << '\n';
    //std::cout << foo.offset(c) << '\n';
}
```

compiler error:

```
In file included from prog.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple: In instantiation of ‘struct std::tuple_element<1u, std::tuple<C&> >’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:680:12:   recursively required from ‘struct std::tuple_element<2u, std::tuple<B&, C&> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:680:12:   required from ‘struct std::tuple_element<3u, std::tuple<A&, B&, C&> >’
prog.cpp:79:22:   recursively required from ‘typename std::enable_if<((std::tuple_size<_Tp>::value != INDEX) && (! std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type, T>::value)), unsigned int>::type Foo<Tuple>::offset(const T&) [with unsigned int INDEX = 1u; T = A; Tuple = std::tuple<A&, B&, C&>; typename std::enable_if<((std::tuple_size<_Tp>::value != INDEX) && (! std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type, T>::value)), unsigned int>::type = unsigned int]’
prog.cpp:79:22:   required from ‘typename std::enable_if<((std::tuple_size<_Tp>::value != INDEX) && (! std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type, T>::value)), unsigned int>::type Foo<Tuple>::offset(const T&) [with unsigned int INDEX = 0u; T = A; Tuple = std::tuple<A&, B&, C&>; typename std::enable_if<((std::tuple_size<_Tp>::value != INDEX) && (! std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type, T>::value)), unsigned int>::type = unsigned int]’
prog.cpp:101:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:680:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >’
     struct tuple_element<__i, tuple<_Head, _Tail...> >
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:38:0,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:84:11: error: declaration of ‘struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >’
     class tuple_element;
           ^
```

Comment: C++1y, you could simply do something like `(size_t)((void*)&tuple_-(void*)&std::get<T>(tuple))`. Else you need a specialization of the function to prevent the unrolling going past the end of the tuple.

Comment: This smells like a g++ bug to me, based on a quick google of *`"error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >’"`*.

Comment: @cdhowie do you expect a tuple_element behind the tuple_size to be a complete type?, that empty `tuple<>` results from recursive nature of tuple_element

Comment: @PiotrS. Crossed wires while I was looking at this I guess and I confused one thing for another -- I know that `std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<>>` is not a complete type but was looking at a different type for some reason. It's too early to look at recursive templates, I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except for one issue.

The problem is that you construct a `std::tuple` using the `std::tie()` helper function, which results in a *tuple of references* - `std::tuple<A&, B&, C&>`.

On the other hand, you have `offset(const T& t)` where the deduced type `T` can be just `A`, `B`, or `C` (that is, the reference is not part of the deduced type, only of the parameter's type). That said, your condition `is_same<tuple_element<...>::type, T>` always fails because one type is a reference, whereas the other is not, e.g. `std::is_same<A&, A>`. To solve this, you should first *decay* the type (or at least *remove a reference*) before it is compared to another one for equality.

Having said that, your every condition should look as follows:

```
std::is_same<typename std::decay<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type>::type, T>::value
//           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^                                               ~~~~~~^
```

or in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
std::is_same<std::decay_t<typename std::tuple_element<INDEX, Tuple>::type>::type>, T>::value
//           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^                                                      ^
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8a772344c145abd)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want something like:

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple> struct get_index;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct get_index<T, std::tuple<T, Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename Tail, typename... Ts>
struct get_index<T, std::tuple<Tail, Ts...>> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + get_index<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>::value> {};
```

And then replace all your offset method by

```
template <typename T>
std::size_t
offset(const T&)
{
    return array_[get_index<T&, Tuple>::value];
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/SWrSKG).

Notice than in your example `Tuple` is `std::tuple<A&, B&, C&>` and you test for equality with `A`...